# Uniformly convergence of $\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} {1 \over 1+(n+x)^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let me suggest the question in my lecture's note.

Show this series uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

### $\sum_{n=0} ^{\infty}  {1 \over  1+(n+x)^2}$

---

One thing sure, we can easily show it by using Weierstrass thm that by $\sum {1 \over  1+(n+x)^2} \leq \sum M_n$ (Here the $M_n$ only depend on the variable $n$) Here is my trial for finding the $M_n$

I found my lecture's solution in his note. He said

Say $a>0$, $\vert n \vert > 4a$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence, $\forall x \in [-a,a]$, ${1 \over  1+(n+x)^2} < {1 \over  1+ n^2/2}$

First, I can't guess how could he discover the $n$ s.t. $\vert n \vert > 4a$. So, I tried different method like the below

### ${1 \over  1+(n+x)^2} < {1 \over  (n+x)^2} <  {1 \over  4nx}$

For taking the $M_n$, only left step is getting rid of the $x$. What should I do next step?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: None of the summands is defined on the whole $\Bbb R$. Are you sure about the question?

Comment: Indeed this series is uniformly convergent on $[0, + \infty )$ simply because $$\frac{1}{1+(n+x)^2} < \frac{1}{1+n^2}=M_n$$ Similarly you can prove uiform convergence on every set of the form $[A ; + \infty)$, however I'm not sure about the whole real line.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The summands denominator are always positive, they are 1+ a square.

Comment: @Crostul Sure. That was nonsense.

Comment: @Crostul, Yes it is definitely true when considering the $[0,\infty)$ But the my problem was the negative case. The question required on $\mathbb{R}$ not just $\mathbb{R^+}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @Crostul, I found my lecture's solution. Please give me some seconds for editing my question.

Comment: It is not uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @xpaul, Would you tell me the reason why did you conclude like that?

Comment: The lecturer is wrong.  The $n$'th term is $1$ at $x = -n$.

Comment: Yes! He made wrong conclusion. Thanks for everyone. :)

Comment: @se-hyuckyang, the reason is from RRL's answer which you already accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition for uniform convergence of a series $\sum f_n(x)$ for $x \in D$ is that $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$.  This follows from the Cauchy criterion, and  is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in D} |f_n(x)| = 0.$

In this case, we have with $x_n = -n+1/n \in D=(-\infty,0),$

$$\sup_{x \in D }|f_n(x)| =\sup_{x \in D} \frac{1}{1+(n+x)^2} \geqslant \frac{1}{1+(n+ x_n)^2} = \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} \to 1$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ the convergence cannot be uniform on $(-\infty,0)$.

As shown in a comment convergence on $[0,\infty)$ is, in fact, uniform by the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Why not put $x=-n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  That gets the job done as well.